# Combining if with not and or

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

```
if not xclass == '1' or xclass == '2' or xclass == '3': 
    print 'Invalid'
```

How can I make this list of conditions work?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: `class` is a reserved word. How does this not throw `SyntaxError` before it even runs?

Comment: @Billy then please [edit] your question and fix the code. We can't help you if you don't give us the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, I usually use `any`

```
if not any((foo == '1', bar == '2', baz == '3')):
    print 'Invalid'
```

`any` returns `True` as soon **as one of the conditions** in the provided iterable is `True`. So it is like a list of `or` but is way easier to manage, especialy when you start having a combination of values to verify and `not`s.

[official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)

You should use `any`, `next`, `all`,... these are really powerful and useful buit-in helpers.